# How to concatenate keras layers beyond the last axis

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tried to concatenate keras layers beyond the last axis.

```
concat_layer = keras.layers.concatenate([layer1,layer2],axis=3);
```

The shapes of layer1 and layer2 are both (?,7,7),for now I want it become (?,7,7,2) rather than (?,7,14). If I wrote like axis=3, it returns "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"...

What should I do? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Keras [backend](https://keras.io/backend/) has an *expand_dim* operation, which you can you use with the [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer. Try:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda, concatenate

layer1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=3))(layer1)
layer2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=3))(layer2)
concat_layer = concatenate([layer1, layer2], axis=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Reshape the layer to the required dimension and then use the newly added axis to concatenate

```
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate

layer1 = Reshape((7, 7, 1))(layer1)
layer2 = Reshape((7, 7, 1))(layer2)
concat_layer = concatenate([layer1, layer2], axis=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keras.backend.stack`, e.g.:

```
keras.backend.stack([layer1,layer2],axis=-1)
```

Comment: thx, but I tried it, and throw a error "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'"